# SQL statement not calculating the SUM with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return the total of two columns based on the locations associated to each of the two columns.
When I use the OR statement like such:

```
$query = "SELECT  ec.ElecEnergy, ec.GasEnergy, ua.City, 
    SUM(ec.ElecEnergy) AS ecTotal, 
    SUM(ec.GasEnergy) AS gcTotal
FROM energyconsumption ec INNER JOIN
     useraccount ua
     ON ec.User = ua.id
     WHERE ua.City ='London'
     OR City ='Manchester'
     OR City ='Luton'
     OR City ='Newcastle'
     OR City ='Birmingham'
     OR City ='Blackburn'


     GROUP BY ec.ElecEnergy, ec.GasEnergy, ua.City
     ORDER BY ec.ID ASC";






        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $r = array();
        if($result->num_rows){

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                array_push($r, array( 'ElecConsump' => $row['ecTotal'],'GasConsump' =>$row['gcTotal'],
                'Location' => $row['City']


                ));

                }

        } echo json_encode(array('results' => $r));
```

It just returns everything from my database. What I want is a sum of the columns based for each of the cities I have listed.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're returning the actual amount as well as the SUM! That prevents the server from aggregating the values. You should also add `GROUP BY ua.City`

Comment: not sure if this is a problem, but are you missing the prefixes of Cities? (City vs ua.City)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to include `city` in the `group by`, rather than the columns you are aggregating.  Remember, the columns in the `group by` define the rows that are being returned, with unique combinations on each row.

Also, use `in` . . . much simpler to write and read:

```
SELECT ua.City, SUM(ec.ElecEnergy) AS ecTotal, SUM(ec.GasEnergy) AS gcTotal
FROM energyconsumption ec INNER JOIN
     useraccount ua
     ON ec.User = ua.id
WHERE ua.City IN ('London', 'Manchester', 'Luton', 'Newcastle', 'Birmingham', 'Blackburn')
GROUP BY ua.City
ORDER BY ua.City ASC;
```

Notice that I also changed the `ORDER BY` clause -- assuming you are returning one row per city.

If you want the totals for all the cities combined, then:

- remove the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.
- remove `ua.city` from the `SELECT`.